# Formatting Django's horizontal_filter choices

Tags: django, django-admin

The code below works, except that Class B's fields name3 and name4 are joined together in filter_horizontal.  My question how do I format name3 and name4?  For exampleif name3 = 'a' and name4= 'b', with filter_horizontal it shows 
'a b'. How do I format it to something like 'b (a)' ?

```
model.py

class A(models.Model):
    name1 = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    name2 = models.ManyToManyField('B')

class B(models.Model):
    name3 = models.CharField(max_length=15) 
    name4 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
=============================
admin.py 

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import A,B

class AAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = [ 'name1', 'name2'] 
    filter_horizontal = ('name1','name2')

admin.site.register(A, AAdmin)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you do it:

```
class AAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = [ 'name1', 'formatname2'] 
    filter_horizontal = ('name1','formatname2')

    def formatname2(self, obj):
        return "{0} ({1})".format(obj.name2.name4, obj.name2.name3)
```